# Apply one acceleration to all objects

Tags: physics, force-fields

Can I make a force field that affects every object according to their mass, so that all objects accelerate at say 1 m/s^2, is that possible in blender? If not possible via UI is it possible via scripting or animation nodes?

Comment: Isn't that what gravity does?

Comment: Right but gravity is very limited, it can only be in one direction for every scene and must be applied to all objects for every scene, I can't exclude an rigid body from gravity for example.